# ckeditor stripping strings in this format <me@email.com>

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use ckeditor 4 and I set my config with:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

However, my string in this format "<peter@gmail.com>" is totally stripped. When I check chrome inspector, I get this error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  peter@gmail.com:has(div.gmail_extra)".
```

How do I allow this format in ckeditor? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is not an html tag:
    `<me@email.com>`

If you need to use that, encode `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`:

```
&lt;me@email.com&gt;
```

Comment: I already encoded it but still not displaying. But when I enclose it like:

    &lt;<a>me@gmail.com</a>&gt;

It will display in the wysiwyg.